# Adding a class to a region: how is the class correctly added?

Tags: theming

In the book Definite guide in Drupal I found the code below for adding a class to specific regions. I just don't understand how Drupal knows which regions should use the CSS class. There is only an `if` statemente which checks that the regions "sidebar" etc exist, but I can't see how Drupal adds the class to the specific regions. Did I misunderstand the code?

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_region().
 */
function dgd7_preprocess_region(&$variables) {
  $region = $variables['region'];

  // Sidebars and content area need a good class to style against. You should
  // not be using id's like #main or #main-wrapper to style contents.

  if (in_array($region, array('sidebar_first', 'sidebar_second', 'content')) {
    $variables['classes_array'][] = 'main';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is not checking if those regions exist, but for which region the function is being invoked. `hook_preprocess_region()` (of which `dgd7_preprocess_region(&$variables)` is an implementation) is invoked once for each region the page contains.

The fact `$variables['region']` contains the name of the region being handled is clearer in the documentation for [`template_preprocess_region()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_region/7.x) which says:

> Prepares the values passed to the theme_region function to be passed into a pluggable template engine. **Uses the region name to generate a template file suggestions.**

Since the code the function uses is the following one, `$variables['region']` contains the region name.

```
$variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'region__' . $variables['region'];
```

Comment: Thanx a lot...a little bit confused, but really appreciate your help. Need to think it over.

Comment: So you mean, that - simply said - the whole function dgd7_preprocess_region() will run only for sidebar first, sidebar second and  content regions? And it will create a class 'main' for all of them? Sorry, this is confusing. I found the in_array() function and it should check if some "elements" are present in an array (here $region)...https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_in_array.asp. Jeez :(.

Comment: No, `in_array()` checks the first argument is contained in the array passed as second argument. It's a quick way to check if `$region` has one of a set of values. You could use `if ($region == 'sidebar_first' || $region == 'sidebar_second' ||  $region == 'content') {}`, but the code using `in_array()` is easier to change, IMO.

Comment: `hook_preprocess_region()` is invoked once for each region present in the page, not once for all the regions present in a page. If you check the value of `$region`, it will get a different value each time it is invoked for a region in the page.

Comment: I see, so my idiocy was based on misinterpretation of in_array function :). Jeez, if it werent for you I d spend the rest of my life on solving it! Thank you.